# Connect to Outlook Capture More Columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, calendar, task-list, outlook

I created a task list and have connected the list to Outlook.  All works well, but is there a way that I can capture more column types from SharePoint into Outlook?  By default the title is entered into the "Subject" field in Outlook. Can it function similar to regular Calendar in SharePoint that allows me to show what fields I want to have shown on the calendar (ex. Choice Column...etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to change which columns from your task list are displaying the view you have in Outlook? If so, you can use these steps once you've synced the task list to your Outlook client:

1. When viewing your synced task list in Outlook, click on the 'View' tab in the ribbon and select the 'Add Columns' option in the 'Arrangement' section.
   [image]
2. Use the 'Show Columns' modal that displays to add or remove columns from the synced list.
   [image]

Hope this helps!

-Drew